# Is there any way to add Google Drive API's 'Save to Drive' button in lwc?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, integration, html

I used the following code which is provided by Google to add '[Save to Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/savetodrive)' button on our web page to save files to Drive:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
```

I saved the above script in static resource and loaded it using `loadScript()` in js.

```
<div class="g-savetodrive"
   data-src="//example.com/path/to/myfile.pdf"
   data-filename="My Statement.pdf"
   data-sitename="My Company Name">
</div>
```

This code doesn't seems to be working in LWC. Will it not work in Aura/LWC? Can someone please help?